# mongoDB - $push _id to specific users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to push an _id to specific users, but unfortunately it does not work as expected.
Here is my code:

```
var chatId = Chat.insert(privateMessage);
Users.update({_id: {$in: participants}}, {$push: {chat: chatId}});
```

I want to push the `chatId` to all users within the `participants` array.
The `participants` array looks like this: `[ '3JsJP8MJZXRdACJqs', 'En2mTYgRj3BkHc6AW', 'p3kgiZbjYpvvYAWYs' ]`. After checking the result, I noticed that **only** the user with the `_id`: `3JsJP8MJZXRdACJqs` had the `chatId` in the document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `update()` method updates a single document. To update multiple documents, use the `multi` option in the `update()` method.

as:

```
Users.update({
    _id : {
        $in : participants
    }

}, {
    $push : {
        chat : chatId
    }
}, 

   {multi : true}
);
```

**Refer**: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#update-multiple-documents